# Hole in concrete floor from floor anchor

Tags: concrete, basement, hole

I have a small hole in my basement floor from a leftover floor anchor similar to http://www.lowes.com/pd_79553-2191-50098___?productId=3044000. The anchor is now gone, and apparently over the years the hole has had some small amount of dirt and moisture pushing up through it.

I believe it is the source of a water leak during heavy rain. At the very least, it will be a point of concern for anyone buying the house. (I'm planning on selling in the next year).

I need to get this hole sealed properly. Preferably in a way that won't make it obvious that a hole was there (though this concern is very much secondary). What would be the right way to do this?

Comment: I presume the unstated question is "how can I seal this". I believe the usual answer is hydraulic patching cement.

Comment: @keshlam That sounds like an answer.

Comment: @keshlam Yes, that does sound like an answer. I plan to research hydraulic patching cement on my own. If you would be willing to post as an answer, could you include a link to the correct stuff I should be getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd want to use a products like this:
http://www.homedepot.com/p/Quikrete-1-qt-Concrete-Crack-Seal-864000/100318507

It'll be hard to get concrete mix into such a small hole without leaving a void. This crack sealer is designed for smaller holes & cracks. Documentation here: http://www.quikrete.com/PDFs/Projects/RepairingConcrete.pdf

Comment: I used this to fill in the two holes I had. Seems to have done the trick.